# I have some problems in getting the logic of a program

Tags: php

I have following codes to reverse a number:

```
<?php 
    function reverse_num($num){
        $sum = 0;
        while(floor($num)){
            $newnum = $num%10;
            $sum = $sum * 10 + $newnum;
            $num = $num/10;
        }
        return $sum;
    }
    echo reverse_num(98);
    ?>
```

In this code, when the loop is first time initialized, it is returning 8 as a value of  $sum. But I wanted to know where exactly it is storing the value? Is it changing the value of $sum(above while loop) from 0 to 8? Could you give me a rough sketch where it is storing the sum returned first time? My question is that whether the value of $sum initialized as 0 on the top remains same or it changes because whenever we echo $sum on the top, it will always show 0. So we can not directly see whether it is changing or not?

Edit:
Is it okay to say?(see comments):

```
<?php 
    function reverse_num($num){
        $sum = 0; //Logically this becomes $sum = 8; Is it oaky to say?
        while(floor($num)){
            $newnum = $num%10;
            $sum = $sum * 10 + $newnum;
            $num = $num/10;
        }
        return $sum;
    }
    echo reverse_num(98);
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking; a variable changes when you assign a new value to it that is different from the value it has. Use a debugger and step through the function to see which variable has what value at any time. Or write it out...

Comment: Follow the value of the `$sum` step by step in the debugger or echo the the value at every iteration of the loop...

Comment: Once you have found an answer which works for you, click the tick next that answer to accept it. This helps other people with your problem know which solution worked for you

Comment: @AdiC, can we say that? See my edit part of the question.

Comment: @Manish You can see how `$sum` changes in the loop by putting some `echo $sum` s inside the loop to see how `$sum` changes inside the loop

Comment: Thank you so much. I wanted to know that specific part especially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The value of `$sum` *IS* changing in the loop**. Before the loop it's initialised as 0 (`$sum = 0`). When the loop runs, the value of `$sum` is changed to the value of `$sum * 10 + $newnum` each iteration of the loop.

The loop returns 8 the first time as (going through your code):

1. `$newnum` = 8 (98 % 10 = 8)
2. `$sum` = 8 ((0 * 10) + 8 = 8)

Comment: Yes the value is changing, but my question is that is $sum = 0;(above while loop) becomes $sum = 8;???

Comment: @Manish In the second line of the loop (`$sum = $sum * 10 + $newnum`), you are changing the value of `$sum` from 0 to the value of `$sum * 10 + $newnum` (which is 8 as (0x10) + 8 is 8). This is why `$sum` becomes 8 after the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks I got your point. Actually I wanted to understand the internal logic of the program.

Comment: @Manish Yes, it's fine to say that `$sum` becomes 8 after the first iteration in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking when/how value of sum changes: see my comments on your code below:

```
function reverse_num($num){

    $sum = 0;
    while(floor($num)){
        //ON 1st iteration, sum = 0 here
        $newnum = $num%10;
        $sum = $sum * 10 + $newnum; //Once you do this, on first iteration sum changes to 8, because here $sum  = 0 * 10 + 8;
        $num = $num/10;
    }
    return $sum;
}
echo reverse_num(98);
```

You can reverse the number using the `strrev` function directly like this:

```
strrev(918); // will return 819
```